# R- Printing a column if 2 other columns meet a value

Tags: r, output, subset, multiple-columns

I have a csv file with multiple columns. I want to print the values of one column if the values of two other columns are above a certain number. I then want to output this to a plain .txt file. I know how to do this on linux using awk but I don't think I can do this with R? (I am new)

Example data-

```
Height  Age  Name
145.2    13   David
170.3    20   Emma
100.1    8    Bob
200.5    23   Ben
176.6    19   Jim
180.7    20   James
165.8    25   Helen
```

So in this example, I am looking to output the name to a .txt file, if height is greater than or equal to (>=) 170 and also if the age is greater or equal to 19.

So it should output Emma, Ben, Jim and James to a new .txt file.

Any help would be great!

I have tried the code Jean suggested, I get this sort of output-

```
Emma, Ben, Jim ... Henry
```

Where it is just showing some of them and not a complete list in one column, just written across the console. I can't see the complete list on R or linux.

I have edited my data, in the real thing there is decimal points in the data which I think is causing the issue. Is there away around this?

Comment: I think I have got the correct output, but on my actual file (There is a large amount of data) it starts to list them then there is an ellipses and I cant see them all. How can I view all of the output, so it is just a long list?

Answer (score 0):

You can print your output to a file this way.

```
sink(file='somefile.txt')
#print(x[x$Height>=170 & x$Age>=19, "Name"])
cat(paste((x[x$Height>=170 & x$Age>=19, "Name"]), collapse="\n"))
sink()
```